# Scalala: IncompatibleClassChangeError in Quickstart

Tags: scala, incompatibility

I'm trying to follow the [Scalala Quickstart Guide](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki/QuickStart).

I built everything with SBT (according to the instructions) and it passed all the tests when I ran `test`.

I'm trying to take advantage of the interactive exploration feature through the console, but I am experiencing a weird error that I do not understand:

```
$ java -jar target/scala_2.8.1/scalala*.min.jar
Loading /var/folders/jZ/jZv35kbwGtSJ1VOYuEDnvU+++TM/-Tmp-/scalala-startup-7730142659387602212.scala...
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: have you tried a clean build?

Comment: @Kim Stebel -- You mean a clean build of Scalala? Yes. I just built it before trying to run the quickstart.

Comment: @Franz Bettag -- No, I don't think so.

Comment: any particular reason for 2.8.1? 2.9.0_1 or 2.9.1 work perfectly fine.